# Pagination in Yii

Tags: php, pagination, yii

I'm implementing a simple widget with pagination and am facing a little problem.

When I have a small number of items on a page, the pagination isn't generated, but everything is okay when I have a lot of items.

The question is: How can I force pagination to render, even if there is only one page with records?

Comment: That's the whole point of a pagination. If there aren't enough items for a 2nd page, you don't need `next` or `previous` buttons, because they would be disabled anyways.

Comment: I understand, so the only way is to override the class?

Comment: Yeah, I think you should override CLinkPager.

Comment: You can override CLinkPager class, you will need to customize init & createPageButtons function to achive your requirment.

Answer (score 1):

You basically just specify a page size on your data provider / active record

```
 $model = new CArrayDataProvider( $dataRow, 
             array('pagination'=> array('pageSize'=>5) ));
```